# how do I customize equation index without losing/hiding it

Tags: equations, tags

to some of my equations, I wish to add  a extra word within the index, without losing the main, automatic indexing. Something like:

```
aaa = aaa (1, word)
bbb = bbb (2)
ccc = ccc (3, otherword)
```

I know about `\tag{---}`, but if I use it, I stop/hide the main automatic index, don't I?

Comment: Will there be many extra words, or is it a different word for each equation with extra word? Also, are these extra words for an index of equations?

Comment: @Bernard one extra word, different for different equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new macro, say `\owntag`, that takes the additional word as argument and does two things:

- increase the counter `equation` by one (so that you get an own number for this equation)
- call the `\tag` command with a concatenation "1, word" of the equation number and your tag

A minimal example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\owntag}[1]{\stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation, #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    aaa = aaa \owntag{word} \\
    bbb = bbb \\
    ccc = ccc \owntag{otherword}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\label` to reference the equations gives `1, word` and `3, otherword`, respectively. An extended version of the macro `\owntag` that allows for other ways of referencing is [shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369919/103046).

Comment: Do you try to referenced a those equations?

Comment: Referencing these equations gives (1, word), (2) and (3, otherword), respectively.

Comment: I know this, but is this what is desired (question for OP actually)?.