# Combining equation number with tag, and referencing both independently

Tags: macros, equations, cross-referencing, tags

In [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369743/103046), we defined a new command `\owntag` to combine the equation number with a user-defined tag:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\owntag}[1]{\stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation, #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    F=ma \owntag[eq:newton]{Newton}
\end{align}

My equation is \eqref{eq:newton}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, we can reference the equation getting the format "1, Newton" as a reference. I would like to extend this command such that I can

- reference to the equation using only the number (i.e. "eq. (1)")
- reference to the equation using only the text (i.e. "eq. (Newton)")

To implement the first goal, I tried to add an additional counter, set it to the value of the equation counter, do `\refstepcounter` and put the `\label` right after it, but still get "(1, Newton)" as a reference:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcounter{equationwotag}

\newcommand{\owntag}[2][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{
    \stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation, #2}
}{
    \setcounter{equationwotag}{\value{equation}}\label{#1}\stepcounter{equation}\stepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation, #2}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    F=ma \owntag[eq:newton]{Newton}
\end{align}

My equation is \eqref{eq:newton}.

\end{document}
```

How can I achieve these two methods of referencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you you add a `\label{eq:Newton}` what happens is that the current "value" of `\@currentlabel` is stored in the aux file as the associated label. So one way to do what you want is to set `\@currentlabel` accordingly and then add the `\label`. There is an added complication in that the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package redefines `\label` so that it does a little bit of error checking and, in particular, gives an error if you try to define two labels inside an equation environment like `align`. To get around this we have to use `\ltx@label` instead of `\label`, which is the "normal unguarded" latex `\label`.

Finally, I misread your MWE and thought that you wanted an optional argument that gives a short version of the label. This seems like a good feature to have but it requires a little more trickery as we need to insert a "variable" inside the label name.

I have set it up so that after `\owntag[<short label>]{<tag>}`:

- `\ref{Eq:<label>}` gives the "full label"  with the equation number and the "own tag"
- `\ref{eq:<label>}` gives only the equation number
- `\ref{tag:<label>}` gives only the "own tag"

The upshot is that you can now produce this:

[image]

using the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\owntag}[2][\relax]{% \owntag[short label]{tag}
  \ifx#1\relax\relax\def\owntag@name{#2}\else\def\owntag@name{#1}\fi% base label
  \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation, #2}%
  \expandafter\ltx@label\expandafter{eq:\owntag@name}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\theequation, #2}\expandafter\ltx@label\expandafter{Eq:\owntag@name}%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}\expandafter\ltx@label\expandafter{tag:\owntag@name}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    F=ma \owntag[newton]{Newton}% with optional argument
\end{align}

My equation is \eqref{Eq:newton}. The equation number by itself is
\eqref{eq:newton} and the tag is \eqref{tag:newton}.

\begin{align}
    E=mc^2\owntag{Einstein}% no optional argument
\end{align}

My equation is \eqref{Eq:Einstein}. The equation number by itself is
\eqref{eq:Einstein} and the tag is \eqref{tag:Einstein}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using the macro from user30471.

```
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i} = 0 \qquad \mathrm{or} \qquad \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{u} = 0 
    \owntag[example]{Mass conservation}
\end{align}

the mass conservation equation \eqref{mass}.
```

gives the output:

[image]

Eventually what worked for me is the following code:

```
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:mass}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i} = 0 \qquad \mathrm{or} \qquad \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{u} = 0 
    \tag{\theequation ,\ Mass\ Conservation}
    \label{dummy}
\end{equation}

This is the mass conservation equation \eqref{eq:mass}. This is its dummy label \eqref{dummy}.
```

with the output

[image]