# How to number a group of equations together and align them with others

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, align, tags

I'm currently using this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{align}  
\partial_{tt} u\,-\Delta u\,&=\,0 \qquad &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\notag\\  
u\,&=\,g_{D} \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{D}\notag\\  
\partial_{t} u\,+\partial_{\eta} u\,&=\,0 \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N}\label{eq:u}\\  
\partial_{\eta}u\,&=\,g_{\eta} \qquad   &sobre\quad&[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N2}\notag\\  
u\,&=\,u_{0} \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\notag\\  
\partial_{t}u\,&=\,v_{0} \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\notag 
\intertext{Para reducir el orden del sistema hacemos los siguientes cambios de variables:}  
\vec{q}\,&=\,\nabla u  \qquad  &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:q}\\  
v\,&=\,\partial_{t}u  \qquad  &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:v}\\  
\intertext{De esto se obtiene el siguiente sistema de ecuaciones diferenciales parciales de primer orden:}  
\partial_{t} v\,-\nabla\cdot\vec{q}\,&=\,0 \qquad &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:dtv}\\  
\partial_{t} \vec{q}\,-\nabla v\,&=\,0 \qquad &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:dtq}\\  
u\,=\,g\quad ;\quad v\,&=\,\partial_{t}g_{D} \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{D}\label{eq:vD}\\  
v\,+\vec{q}\cdot\eta\,&=\,0 \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N}\label{eq:vN}\\  
\vec{q}\cdot\eta\,&=\,g_{\eta}\qquad & sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N2}\\  
u\,=\,u_{0}\quad ;\quad\vec{q}\,=\,\nabla u_{0}\,&=\,\vec{\mu} \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\label{eq:q0}\\  
v\,=\,v_{0}\,&=\,\omega \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\label{eq:v0}  
\end{align}  
\end{document}
```

Wich gives out this:
[image: pdf output]
I have a couple of problems with this, first, I would like the numbering in the first set of equations to be between the lines, second, when referencing this equations the generated hyperlink leads to the equation with the label, not the group.

I don't like using `equation` + `aligned` because the alignment is not the same than with the rest of the equations. This is using `equation` + `aligned` on the first set of equations.
[image: pdf output using equation and aligned]
I'm not a fan of it but I might end up using it if there is no choice.

The question would be:
*how do I get the alignment obtained with `align` with the numbering obtained with `equation`+ `aligned`?*

Comment: Look at environment gather* from amsmath.

Comment: sadly `gather` enviroment doesn't seem to support multiple `&` on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution has two steps:

1. Define the reference to the equation at the line that you want to reference to, without printing it immediately. Borrowing from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369919/103046), I define a macro `\firstlabel` that works just like label but can be used inside a line of align that has no tag present. Insert this in the line that you want to jump to on clicking the hyperlink to it.
2. Print the tag at the place where you want it to appear without defining a reference point. You can use `\tag*` to define the tag, and `\raisebox` to move it vertically between the two middle lines.

In your example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstlabel}[1]{%
    \def\firsttag@name{#1}%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \expandafter\ltx@label\expandafter{\firsttag@name}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}\firstlabel{eq:u}
\partial_{tt} u\,-\Delta u\,&=\,0 \qquad &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\notag\\
u\,&=\,g_{D} \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{D}\notag\\
\partial_{t} u\,+\partial_{\eta} u\,&=\,0 \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N}\tag*{\raisebox{-0.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\eqref{eq:u}}}\\
\partial_{\eta}u\,&=\,g_{\eta} \qquad   &sobre\quad&[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N2}\notag\\
u\,&=\,u_{0} \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\notag\\
\partial_{t}u\,&=\,v_{0} \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\notag
\intertext{Para reducir el orden del sistema hacemos los siguientes cambios de variables:}
\vec{q}\,&=\,\nabla u  \qquad  &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:q}\\
v\,&=\,\partial_{t}u  \qquad  &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:v}\\
\intertext{De esto se obtiene el siguiente sistema de ecuaciones diferenciales parciales de primer orden:}
\partial_{t} v\,-\nabla\cdot\vec{q}\,&=\,0 \qquad &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:dtv}\\
\partial_{t} \vec{q}\,-\nabla v\,&=\,0 \qquad &en\quad &[0;T]\times\Omega\label{eq:dtq}\\
u\,=\,g\quad ;\quad v\,&=\,\partial_{t}g_{D} \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{D}\label{eq:vD}\\
v\,+\vec{q}\cdot\eta\,&=\,0 \qquad &sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N}\label{eq:vN}\\
\vec{q}\cdot\eta\,&=\,g_{\eta}\qquad & sobre\quad &[0;T]\times\partial\Omega_{N2}\\
u\,=\,u_{0}\quad ;\quad\vec{q}\,=\,\nabla u_{0}\,&=\,\vec{\mu} \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\label{eq:q0}\\
v\,=\,v_{0}\,&=\,\omega \qquad &en\quad &\lbrace0\rbrace\times\Omega\label{eq:v0}
\end{align}
\eqref{eq:u}
\end{document}
```

[image]