# Add text to the numbering of equations

Tags: equations

In my thesis, I have two kinds of equations from two different topics. I wanted to label them in my text like:

> some text
>
> a^2+b^2 = c^2     (1.1 EM)
>
> some other text
>
> A^2 + b^2 = c^2    (1.1 GR)

But I want it to be that I can pass the EM/GR as an argument to the equations. I want also be able to reference to my equations such that it is written like

Refering to Eq. (1.1 GR) one can see...

Therefore my question was if anyone has an idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369890

Comment: Are *all* equation numbers in the document tagged with either an `EM` or a `GR` suffix? Or just some?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `subequations`: you just need to add a suitable label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:group}
Some text
\begin{equation}\label{eq:EM}
a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{\ref{eq:group} EM}
\end{equation}
More text
\begin{equation}\label{eq:GR}
a^2+b^2=c^2 \tag{\ref{eq:group} GR}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
Still more text
\begin{equation}\label{eq:again}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq:EM} and \eqref{eq:GR} and \eqref{eq:again}

\end{document}
```

Can we do this automatically? Yes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcounter{namedsubequations}
\newenvironment{namedsubequations}
 {%
  \subequations
  \stepcounter{namedsubequations}%
  \label{namedsubequations@\thenamedsubequations}%
 }
 {\endsubequations\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\addname}[1]{\tag{\ref{namedsubequations@\thenamedsubequations} #1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{namedsubequations}
Some text
\begin{equation}\label{eq:EM}
a^2+b^2=c^2 \addname{EM}
\end{equation}
More text
\begin{equation}\label{eq:GR}
a^2+b^2=c^2 \addname{GR}
\end{equation}
\end{namedsubequations}
Still more text
\begin{equation}\label{eq:again}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq:EM} and \eqref{eq:GR} and \eqref{eq:again}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `amsmath` package provides the `\tag` macro for just this occasion.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}     % for '\tag' macro
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{section}    % just for this example

Some text
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \tag{1.1 EM} \label{eq:em}
\end{equation}

More text
\begin{equation}
A^2 + b^2 = c^2 \tag{1.1 GR} \label{eq:gr}
\end{equation}

Still more text
\stepcounter{equation} % let the internal 'equation' counter catch up
\begin{equation}
A^2 + b^2 = c^2 \label{eq:still}
\end{equation}

Referring to Eq.\ \eqref{eq:gr} one can see \dots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution with a new environment `labelledequation`. It takes one argument, which is the text that will be placed next to the equation number. I also defined a starred version of the environment, which is exactly the same except that it does not increase the `equation` counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{labelledequation}[1]{%
    \begin{equation}
    \refstepcounter{equation}
    \tag{\theequation{} #1}
}{\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\newenvironment{labelledequation*}[1]{%
    \begin{equation}
    \tag{\theequation{} #1}
}{\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{labelledequation}{EM}
\label{eqEM}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2.
\end{labelledequation}
some more text
\begin{labelledequation*}{GM}
\label{eqGM}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2.
\end{labelledequation*}
references to the equations work! \eqref{eqEM} and \eqref{eqGM}
\end{document}
```